# First element not with class

Tags: jquery

I want to select the *first* element that does *not* have a class `.disabled`.

I tried these without success:

```
$('.selected:first:not(".disabled")').addClass('first');
```

and

```
$('.selected:first').not(".disabled").addClass('first');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to get all the element with class 'selected' but without class 'disabled' then get the first of them.

```
$('.selected:not(.disabled)').first().addClass('disabled');
```

or

```
$('.selected:not(.disabled):first').addClass('disabled');
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5LuXD/1/

Answer (score 5):

```
$('.selected:not(.disabled):first').addClass('first');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$('.selected').not('.disabled')[0]
```

Comment: This is very ugly. $($('.selected').not('.disabled')[0]).addClass('disabled');

Answer (score 1):

Your code:

```
$('.selected:first:not(".disabled")').addClass('first');
```

this code selects the first element with `selected` class and than check is the the selected element not have `disabled` class.

[Fiddle With Your code Output](http://jsfiddle.net/5LuXD/3/)

**Answer :-**

First you need to select the elements which not have css class `disabled`.

Using:

```
$('.selected:not(.disabled)');
```

And after that select the first element into the matched element;

```
$('.selected:not(.disabled)').first();
```

Try this:

```
$('.selected:not(.disabled)').first().addClass('first');
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5LuXD/2/)